# Replace the Outlook 2010 Send-Button?

Tags: c#, outlook, vsto, outlook-addin, office-2010

I'm looking for a solution for the following problem. Can anybody help me out?

I need to replace Outlooks Send-button with a dropdown-button like the "Von" (From) button in my screenshot.

FYI: The new Send-DropDown button will have three functions:
1. Outlooks default send function (the normal sendbutton)
2. Send & Archive Mail
3. Send & Archive Mail+Attachments

[image: Outlook Screenshot]

Can anyone help me out? Is it possible to do a replacment like i want? if not - does anyone have an other solution for my problem?

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to hide the send button (see here: http://help.lockergnome.com/office/hide-disable-button-Outlook-2007--ftopict1010132.html) and then add your own button to the form. The add-in SDK should have all the functionality you need.

Comment: Well. I tested that before. I cant hide the button. Do you know its ID or even better: Can you give me some hints or an example?

Comment: Okay. First: Thank you for your answers, so far. I tried 3037 before i asked the question in here. It doesn't work. Any other hints?

Answer (score 0):

It could be that the ID is 2617.

3037 is the send command in the file menu.

I need this myself so I'll try it out and edit accordingly.
Anyone who can help posting the code to use these ID's is very welcome.

(edit)
    inspector.CommandBars().FindControl(, 2617).Visible = False

It should work but it doesn't.
If anyone could help out...